# C++ do while loop with cin

Tags: c++

Below is my do while loop with cin
There a bit of problem, when user enter Fullname then press enter.
The pointer will go to next line. 
until user press enter again, then it prompt Email address, how do i make it prompt email address right after full name is entered on my code below

Terminal Look:

```
Full Name: John
Email Address: some_email@gmail.com
```

My test.cpp code:

```
emailAddress= "";
fullname = "";
counter = 0;

if(department_selection!="")
{

while(fullname=="")
{
if(counter>0)
{
//so it wont print twice
cout << "Full Name: ";
}

getline(cin,fullname);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
counter++;
}

counter = 0;

while(emailAddress=="")
{
if(counter>0)
{
//so it wont print twice
cout << "Email Address: ";
}

getline(cin,emailAddress);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
counter++;
}

}// if department selection not blank
```

Still same issue. i need to tab enter once then it prompt for email address.

**Latest Update: Manage to fix it. I make changes to the code and it is this version:**

```
do
{
  if(counter==0)
  {
     //so it wont print twice
     cout << "Full Name: ";
  }
  if(counter>1)
  {
     //so it wont print twice
     cout << "Full Name: ";
  }

  getline(cin,fullname);
  counter++;
} while (fullname=="");

counter = 0;

do
{
  if(counter==0)
  {
     //so it wont print twice
     cout << "Email Address: ";
  }
  if(counter>1)
    {
         cout << "Email Address: ";
    }

  getline(cin,emailAddress);
  counter++;
} while (emailAddress=="");
```

Comment: You should use a variable that is local to the scope of the do/while loops. I assume counter is declared outside of both while loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `if(counter>0)` use `if(counter==0)`

My working test app:

```
int counter = 0;
string fullname, emailAddress;
do
{
  if(counter==0)
  {
     //so it wont print twice
     cout << "Full Name: ";
  }

  getline(cin,fullname);
  counter++;
} while (fullname=="");

counter = 0;

do
{
  if(counter==0)
  {
     //so it wont print twice
     cout << "Email Address: ";
  }

  getline(cin,emailAddress);
  counter++;
} while (emailAddress=="");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for length and then @.

```
 do
    {
    ...
    }while(fullname.length()<2);

    do
    {
    ...
    }while(emailAddress.length()<3||emailAddress.find("@")==string::npos);
```

Comment: What does input sanitation have to do with the prompt not appearing when it should?

Comment: @steveg89:- OP's code has no error.http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q240015&ID=KB;EN-US;q240015 ..what should I then suggest :)

Comment: It does have an error. Look at my post and re-read his question. He was getting an extra getline before getting his prompt, because his condition for showing the prompt was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the clear() and ignore() functions too to ignore words already stored in the input

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer to his question.

Comment: It should resolve the problem - what more does an answer need?

Comment: Hmm how should i change it to make it work with your clear and ignore.

Comment: Once you've got the input stored, use like this:

Comment: var.clear(); or var.ignore(); for the string variable storing the input

Comment: Unnecessary: read up on getline http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to avoid repeating code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

string get_input(const std::string& prompt)
{
    string temp;
    cout << prompt;
    while (!getline(cin, temp) || temp.empty()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    string fullname = get_input("Full Name: ");
    string email = get_input("Email Adress: ");
}
```